# Jquery keep Alive / Any client side interaction?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used a few of the jquery keepalive session plugins with out problem.

I have been asked for something a bit different.

We have some forms (built before I started here) that are fairly large and users work in them for a while.  The page is never refreshed, so they click save and the session is expired and redirect to the login page.

I suggested one of these plugin, that just prompt the user a few minutes before the session expires which would make an ajax call to keep the session alive.

However, they said, will what if they dont see the prompt and miss it all together and logs them out.

They would like me to check

1. Has the user had any interaction with the page in the last 5 minutes.
   If Yes=Ajax call to keep alive the session, and reset timer.
   if No, continue to wait until we get within 2 minutes of session time out and prompt user.

They are trying to avoid the prompt.

Is there anyway with JS/Jquery to know if the page has had any client side interaction?

Comment: well use `mousemove` event when mouse moves reset the timeinterval else call the ajax in a specific time reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a timer to check if they've had any interaction in the last 5 minutes, couldn't you just send your keepalive any time the form has changed? It would eliminate a need for a timer loop and a small payload ajax call just to keep the session alive shouldn't hurt performance at all.

If you still want to keep the timer loop, I would still recommend using the change event on your form elements. Changing the form implies they're interacting with it, and I think that satisfies their requirement.

Edit: Update to use timer

```
var idle = true;

function finalIdleCheck(prompt){
    if(idle){
        if(prompt){
            alert("last warning!");
        }
        //Tighten the idle check time loop; may even want to go < 30s
        setTimeout(finalIdleCheck, 30*1000);
    } else {
        //Ajax stuff to keep session alive
        idle = true; //Reset idle flag
    }
}
function checkIdle(){
    if(idle){
        //Warn them
        alert("You've been idle");
        setTimeout(function(){
            finalIdleCheck(true);
        }, 60*2*1000);
    } else {
        //Ajax stuff to keep session alive
        idle = true; //Reset idle flag
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input").on("change", function(){
        idle = false;
    }
    setTimeout(idleCheck, 60*5*1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your ideas.  I presented the same idea to my manager, but he was worried about bandwidth of always polling the keepalive everytime the end user interacted with the form.  That is why I was thinking, maybe set a flag when the user interacts with the form, then every 5 minutes, if that flag was true then make the ajax call to the keep alive.

Comment: You can still use that logic with the above code. I'll update it accordingly.

Comment: Added a solution using a timer; it's not very DRY, but I just want you to get the idea by separating it into separate functions.

Comment: What about methods like Click, Dblclick, scroll? Would I need to write a function for each of those to set the idle variable to false?

<pre>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input").on("change", function(){
        idle = false;
    }
 
 $("form input").on("scroll", function(){
        idle = false;
    }
 
 $("form input").on("click", function(){
        idle = false;
    }
 $("form input").on("dblclick", function(){
        idle = false;
    } 
 
 
    setTimeout(checkIdle, (60 * idlePoll * 1000));
}
</pre>

Comment: The short answer: yes, if you want all of those to trigger idle resets, you'd need a separate handler for each event.  The longer one: $(document).on("click", function(){}) will cover all clicks (including double click, which isn't an event type). $(document).on("scroll", function(){}) will fire when the page is scrolled; I'd highly recommend against using the scroll event though since it's fired constantly during page scrolls. IMO, I think input click and input change would work.  Maybe even just input "click" and input "keyup" events.

Comment: Thanks.  I will advise the requester.  I think its all a bit much and the regular jquery keepalive plugin should more 99.9% of the time.